# Animating an object with physics engine corona sdk without sprite animation

Tags: mobile, sprite, coronasdk

I have developed a game where I am using physics engine to fall an object. It is working fine. i just need to animate object a little while it falls. Is it possible to make object animated without using sprite animation ?

Or else is there any way where I can combine sprite animation while object falls using physics engine ?

Answer (score 1):

U can rotate or move the object while falling. But sometimes, it may result in incorrect responses.

Otherwise, create a sprite animation, and make its reference point in reference with the falling object with a `timer` or `enterFrame` check.

eg:

```
-- let 'ball' be your physics body
-- let mySprite may your sprite from spritesheet

function placeSprite()
   mySprite.x=ball.x;
   mySprite.y=ball.y;
end
timer.performWithDelay(1,placeSprite,-1)  -- you can also use Runtime listener on enterFrame
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to blow air to just move objects ?

Comment: @HemantMetalia: This may help you: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona/corona-sdk_physics_explosions/